# SQL Where condition remove duplication record in my case

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There is front end system, which is entering such type of data in table, where i have no control.Suppose Table which my query result:

```
Row|    id| entity_code|    entity_value
1            1      Null        22
2            2      Null        28
3            3      Null        32
4            3   Test Entity  Test Entity
5            4      Null        22
```

In above query return table example, front end entering "Test Entity" with new record, not overwrite on id=3

Actually table is to much complex n having dozen of joins,i want WHERE condition for my query where we can remove 
if 'entity_code' column is null and no other record with same 'Entryid' then ok(Row 1,2 n 4) but if 'entity_code' column is  not null(Row 4) and other record with same 'id' is exsist(e.g Row 3).
where condition result look like:

```
Row|  Entry|    entity_code|    entity_value
1        1              Null        22
2        2              Null        28
3        3           Test Entity    32
4        4              Null        22
```

i need that Where Condtion which show such result.

Comment: Post the query that you currently have, please.

Comment: assume simple query
SELECT * from table where ???

Comment: explain why you want entity_value to be 32 and not Test Entity please

Comment: ok for the time being, ignore 32 entity_value
then what will be the query??

Comment: case n also try with temp table, but didn't make any good logic so far

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your logic correctly, this should give you the correct result:

```
SELECT
  e1.min_row row,
  e1.id,
  e2.max_value,
  e.entity_value
FROM
  entity e INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      id,
      MIN(row) min_row
    FROM
      entity
    GROUP BY
      id
    ) e1
  ON e.row = e1.min_row
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      id,
      MAX(entity_code) max_value
    FROM
      entity
    GROUP BY
      id
    ) e2
  ON e1.id = e2.id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b07d3/1).

This is also more simple, works on your sample data but I am not sure it will work on your real data (it depends on your database structure):

```
SELECT
  e1.Row,
  e1.id,
  e2.entity_code,
  e1.entity_value
FROM
  entity e1 LEFT JOIN entity e2
  ON e2.entity_code IS NOT NULL
     AND e1.id = e2.id AND e1.Row!=e2.Row
WHERE
  e1.entity_code IS NULL
```

Comment: Looks Good,
Let me try this solution with my example.